# Docker - Acessar o container por IP no windows

Tags: docker, dotnet-cli

Tenho o docker instalado no windows 10.
Ao executar o nginx consigo acessar pelo endereço http://localhost:8080/.
Contudo, ao utilizar o comando abaixo:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' nome_container
```

O docker exibe o ip 172.17.0.2.
Se eu tentar acessar o nginx por esse endereço não encontra a página.
Isso vem acontecendo com container  criando a partir de imagens do dotnet mesmo seguindo todos passos do tutorial da microsoft.
Alguma sugestão de que possa estar acontecendo?

Comment: Sugiro que leia com a atenção a diretriz da comunidade de como criar uma [boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Entre com mais detalhes sobre o seu problema e sua dúvida, insira os logs de erros entre outros.

Comment: Obrigado Thiago pela dica. Valeu!!

Comment: Sugiro que entenda melhor a configuração da rede docker: http://stack.desenvolvedor.expert/appendix/docker/rede.html

Comment: Vc tentou acessar o ip junto com a porta ? no caso 172.17.0.2:8080